# Cannot create Collection Information -- error when trying to test Cosmos DB trigger locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am testing out developing an Azure Function to read the change feed of a Cosmos DB database. I have created such a function from the Azure portal, but I would like to use VS or VS Code to do so. I have my environment set up using v2.0.3 of the Azure Function Core Tools, but when I try to test the function, I get the following error:

> [10/9/2018 4:33:34 PM] Error indexing method
>   'Functions.workordersTrigger'
>
> [10/9/2018 4:33:34 PM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing
>   method 'Functions.workordersTrigger'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cannot create Collection
>   Information for workorders in database htm with lease wo_leases in
>   database htm : Entity with the specified id does not exist in the
>   system.

Both collections "workorders" and "wo_leases" exist in the db. If I just create a function with a simple HTTP trigger, it works fine, and I can debug in VS Code. It seems to be an issue with the CosmosDB trigger. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Chris. When you run the Trigger locally, are you setting the Connection String correctly to the account you are viewing in the Portal? That error indicates that, in the account that the Connection String is pointing to, the collections do not exist.

Comment: Matias, thanks for answering. I double-checked that I am pointed at the account in the portal. To test, If I change the connection string in local.settings.json, I get a different error "No such host is known" as opposed to "Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system."

Comment: Does your Cosmos DB account have Firewall or Virtual Network enabled?

Comment: There was a vnet enabled, but something must have been improperly configured. I ditched the vnet and manually added my ip address to the firewall and it worked. Thank you very much. I will have to talk to our network guys to see what the proper settings will be.

Comment: You can mix and match. You could add VNET and your particular IP. I will go ahead and add this as an answer for anyone to have for future reference.

Comment: Thanks again. I was worried that I did not have something installed correctly.

Comment: I added an answer with our findings :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message appears if:

1. Any of the collections do not exist in the target account within the specified database
2. Your account has a Firewall rule (either Virtual Network or IP rules) that block access to your current workstation.

For #1, verify if the Connection String is pointing to the correct account and that you can see the collections exist within the database (for this you can use the Azure Portal or browse [Cosmos Explorer](https://cosmos.azure.com) with your connection string).

For #2, verify in the Account there is a rule blocking your access. You can either disable the Firewall rule or add your current IP address (there is a quick link for that in the Portal).