# Unable to connect to Cosmos DB while creating Azure function through Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to both Azure Functions and Cosmos DB. I am trying to set up an Azure function in my local machine that gets triggered on updates on Cosmos DB through Visual Studio.

Initially, I was getting the error `Unable to resolve app setting for property CosmosDBTriggerAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting` but on following this [solution](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1206) I am able to resolve that error, but now getting:

`The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. System.Net.Http: No such host is known. System.Private.CoreLib: No such host is known.`

Here are my `local.settings.json`:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "connectionString": "AccountEndpoint=https://<collectionName>.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=<key>"
  }
}
```

This is my run method if useful:

```
public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "DB-Name",
            collectionName: "CollectionName",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "String I used while setting up the project in VS",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, ILogger log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
                log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].Id);
            }
        }
```

Can someone help? My other question is what is `Account Key` in this case? I am currently using the app name in my Cosmos DB account.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the AccountKey from `Settings -> ConnectionString -> Primary Password` when you click on your [`cosmosDB resource`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320441/where-is-accountkey-for-cosmosdb-in-azure-portal)

and also your connectionString should be something like below,

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "CosmosDB": "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to make sure the database name and collection are right

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the relevant endpoint and account key , but now I am facing a new Error:
`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cannot create Collection Information for <collection> in database <Database> with lease leases in database <database> : , Request URI: //, RequestStats: , SDK: Windows/10.0.18363 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.3.0. Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: , Request URI: //, RequestStats: , SDK: Windows/10.0.18363 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.3.0.`

Comment: Yeah the database name and collection both are correct and are as per the Azure portal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52725891/cannot-create-collection-information-error-when-trying-to-test-cosmos-db-trig

Comment: I checked with the link you have shared. I cross checked but I am connected to the right account and there is no Firewall setting in the cosmos DB account.

Comment: ok thats all i can help. I am sure this is a connectivity issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217348/discussion-between-nikhil-and-sajeetharan).